# How to catch Attribute-events with a StAX XML-parser?

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox

I try to parse an XML file with a StAX XML-parser. It give me `START_ELEMENT` and `END_DOCUMENT` events but no `ATTRIBUTE` events. How can I receive `ATTRIBUTE` events with the StAX parser?

My XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <posts>
        <row name="Jonas"/>
        <row name="John"/>
    </posts>
```

My StAX XML-parser:

```
public class XMLParser {

    public void parseFile(String filename) {
        XMLInputFactory2 xmlif = (XMLInputFactory2) XMLInputFactory2.newInstance();
        xmlif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, Boolean.FALSE);
        xmlif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);
        xmlif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, Boolean.FALSE);
        xmlif.configureForSpeed();

        XMLStreamReader2 xmlr = (XMLStreamReader2) 
                xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename));

                int eventType;
                while(xmlr.hasNext()) {
                    eventType = xmlr.next();
                    switch(eventType) {
                    case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: 
                        if(xmlr.getName().toString().equals("row")) {
                            System.out.println("row");
                        }
                        break;
                    case XMLStreamConstants.ATTRIBUTE: 
                        System.out.println("Attribute");
                        break;
                    case XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT:
                        System.out.println("END");
                        xmlr.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser();
        String filename = "data/test.xml";
        p.parseFile(filename);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain the attributes when you are in the `START_ELEMENT` state.  See the `getAttribute*` methods on `XMLStreamReader`:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getAttributeValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 4):

The whole ATTRIBUTEs even is an odd thing, and as Blaise mentioned, they are not separately reported when using event-based interface. This because attributes are "part of" start element, and need to be handled as such by parsers (to verify uniqueness, bind namespaces etc).