# Java XML Attributes

Tags: java, xml

Recently I started using XML more and now I'm stuck on a weird problem that I can't find a solution to anywhere. How do you read an attribute from a characters event in? I'll show you the XML code and a snippet of the Java code below.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <entity id="Player">
        <state>MainMenu</state>
        <attr id="health">10</attr>
        <attr id="inventory">axe</attr>
        <controller>0</controller>
    </entity>
</config>
```

Java:

```
if (event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("attr"))
{
    event = eventReader.nextEvent();

    System.out.println("Attr: " + event.asCharacters().toString()); 
    System.out.println();

    // Iterator<Attribute> attributes = event.asStartElement().getAttributes();

    /*while (attributes.hasNext())
    {
        Attribute attribute = attributes.next();
        if (attribute.getName().toString().equals("id"))
        {
            e.addAttribute(attribute.getValue(), event.asCharacters().getData());
        }
    }*/

    continue;
}
```

Comment: seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7435674/217324 ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't.  I don't think it even makes sense.  An attribute event *is not* a characters event, so you shouldn't be able to use `asCharacters()` on it successfully at all.

You are meant to pick out the `XMLEvent` representing the start of the element of interest, use `asStartElement()` to get a view of it as a `javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement`, and examine its attributes via either `StartElement.getAttributeByName()` or `StartElement.getAttributes()`.